# key=operator.attrgetter sort order?

Tags: python, django, python-itertools

in my django view, if i import operator, and use the following code:

```
multitags = sorted(multitags, key=operator.attrgetter('date_added'))
```

is there an easy way to reverse the order – such that i get the dates in descending order
(today at top; last week underneath)?

Answer (score 11):

This should work:

```
sorted(multitags, key=operator.attrgetter('date_added'), reverse=True)
```

This document on the python wiki is worth reading through at least once to get an idea of other things worth knowing:

- [Sorting Mini HOWTO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just add `reverse=True` to the keyword arguments with which you're calling `.sorted`!